# Как написать регулярку в js чтобы проверять строку на повторы символов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки

имеется строка английского текста, вида **"aaberjkfadjkaaa"** нужно посчитать количество повторяемых символов, т.е. если символ повторяется **результат+1**, например:
"aabbefg" => 2 # т.к. два элемента повторяются
"AbaBcqwe" => 2 # т.к. регистр не учитывается
как я понимаю одной регулярки не хватит, мне надо сам принцип понять

Comment: Регулярки тут не помогут, регулярки для других целей используются. Тут средствами самого js нужно работать. Проходите по строке и сравниваете каждый символ с теми, которые уже были до этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю под символом английского текста имеются ввиду символы `a-zA-Z`.
Для этого берём регулярку `/([a-z])(?=.*?\1)/gi` с помощью которой находим дублирующиеся символы, затем находим количество уникальных совпадений.

```
var string = "aaberjkfadjkaaa";
var matches = string.match(/([a-z])(?=.*?\1)/gi); // ["a", "a", "j", "k", "a", "a", "a"]
var unique = matches.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i); // ["a", "j", "k"]
var count = unique.length; // 3
```

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно, повторяющиеся символы

Comment: @warnabas Если вам подошёл этот ответ, то отметьте ответ, как принятый.